# In custom Rococo staging and Westend staging network parachain is not producing blocks

Tags: polkadot, parachain, relay-chain, substrate-parachain-template

I have made the rococo relay chain and parachain network successfully following this [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/), and was also able to generate the network with custom keys on relay chain and parachain with `rococo-local` spec file. But the problem arises when I make a network with `rococo-staging` and `westend-staging` everything works fine but the blocks on parachain are not generating, I got the error **`Collation wasn't advertised to any validator`** and after sometime the error changes to **`State Database error: Too many sibling blocks inserted`**.

What I have done is:

- Created `chainSpec` for relay chain with 3 validators using `rococo-staging` and `westend-staging` and added my accounts in it.
- Created `chainSpecRaw` and started the relay chain.
- After successfully starting relay chain, I made the `chainSpec` for parachain with one collator and added my accounts.
- Then I made the `chainSpecRaw` of parachain and started it with `collation:yes`.
- After running both relay chain and parachain, I registered a paraId on relay chain.
- Then added the `wasm runtime` and `genesis state` of parachain on relay chain.
- After this I was able to see the parachain registered on relay chain.
- After completing these steps I faced the above mentioned errors.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/issues/1737

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas issue is that the parachain is not able to produce any block at the starting of the network, it hasn't even produced a single block so there is no state to revert to

Comment: @ShubhamGupta Did you purge the data before starting new network? Could you please share the codebase(github link)?

Comment: @AyushMishra yes I did purge the old data and i am using https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/v0.9.32  for relay chain and for parachain https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/tree/polkadot-v0.9.32

Comment: @ShubhamGupta could you please share info regarding the changes you made to these codebases? The more the better.

Comment: @DaanvanderPlas didn't changed much, just changed `"forceEra": "ForceNone"` to `"forceEra": "NotForcing"` in westend customSpec and on parachain I added `features = ["westend-native"]` in its node's `cargo.toml`

Comment: Please, run your collators with -lparachain::validator-discovery=trace and -lparachain::collator-protocol=trace for having some logs with more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your parachain not producing blocks after registration with `rococo-staging` relaychain is the parameter [session_length_in_blocks](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/c71e872afed296d1825b15ea4b2a74750c1ba647/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L1175). This parameter is set as `None` for `rococo-staging` and `Some(10)` for `rococo-local`.

That's why when you register your parachain with `rococo-local`, you can see your parachain producing blocks in the next epoch after registration. You can verify its value `Developer >> Chain State >> Constants`. When you run with `rococo-local`, you will find its value as 10.

[session_length_in_blocks](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/c71e872afed296d1825b15ea4b2a74750c1ba647/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L1175) sets epochDuration in pallet_babe.

[image]

When you run your chain with `rococo-staging`, you may find its value as `600` because it is set as None and picks default value.

[image]

I tried this scenario on my local and it worked. I followed below steps:

1. I changed [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/v0.9.32/node/service/src/chain_spec.rs#L1172) from `Live` to `Local`
2. Replaced with my validators and created chain-spec with `rococo-staging`.
3. Started relaychain with raw chain spec
4. On parachain-side, I replaced `rococo-local` with `rococo-staging` in chain-spec. Started parachain with raw chain spec.
5. For staring relaychain, parachain and parachain registration, I followed all steps, which are mentioned in this [tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/connect-relay-and-parachains/prepare-a-local-relay-chain/).
6. After registration, it was just showing as `onboarding`
   [image]
7. I waited for `600` blocks.
8. After `600` blocks, it started onboarding `successfully.

[image]

As you can see in my screenshot, onboarding will complete in around 1 hour after it starts. I can see my parachain producing blocks with `rococo-staging`.

[image]

With default parameters, you have to wait. You are free to update values in your runtime for testing.

If this works for you, please mark this answer as acceptable.

Comment: It is working fine now, but still I don't understand why it is not working on `"live"`. If you know please do tell.

Comment: Because you are running on local machine. https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/4692572ecf8de0f9420972f8bf2f072243cf5a94/client/chain-spec/src/lib.rs#L202

Comment: What is the difference between a local and live machine?